# Set ASP.NET database connection pool max life time

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Refer to this document

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.8

How to set the max life time to auto re-creation connection after a specified idle time.

Comment: Just curious why you would want to do this. I normally use sql server connection pooling which handles the creation and allocation of connections.

Comment: Just afraid the long connection make it become unhealthy connection, not fresh connection